# RecyclerView onBindViewHolder indexOutOfBounds trying to paint elements inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have two `Arraylists`, in one of them I have stored `jSONObjects` and in the other one `JSONObjects` too, I'm trying to see if in the first array it contains the elements in the second one and then paint those views but I'm getting `indexOutOfBounds` exception, the items are beign called because the error tells me that index 3 , size 3 which are the elements selected.

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TagsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if(mArrayListElements.contains(mArrayListSelectedTags.get(position))){
            View v = holder.itemView.findViewById(mArrayListElements.indexOf(mArrayListSelectedTags.get(position)));
            v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVincular));
        }
...
```

How do I paint the views inside `mArrayListSelectedTags` from `mArrayListElements`  ?

To be more consistent

`mArrayListElements` have elements from 0 to 15 and `mArrayListSelectedTags` have for example element 0 , 5 , 9  . Then I just want to paint those 3 elements from those 16 that `mArrayListElements` is showing

Edit: I have made this in order to create a view depending on the item position of the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListElementos.size(); i++) {
                View v = holder.itemView.findViewById(mArrayListElementos.indexOf(mArrayListSelectedTags.get(i)));
                v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVincular));
        }
```

But now I'm getting

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object
> ```
>
> reference

Thanks

Comment: What is it you are showing in the RecyclerView? And are you storing the same object in both lists or they are different objects that represent the same data? Also do the json objects have any property that can serve as an id?

Comment: the objects are the same in the two lists, leys say that in one I have 16 JSONObjects , and in the other I have 4 of those 16 stored that I want to paint

Comment: What is it you are showing in the RecyclerView? mArrayListSelectedTags has 4 elements. position refers to the position in the recyclerview. Does this add up to your logic? Meaning are you showing only 4 items?

Comment: thanks juan ! edited my question

Comment: The answer to the NPE is that the view you are looking for is not there. However I suggest checking this link, it may help to get the solution faster. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.

Answer (score 1):

You receiving such exception because you arrays have different size.

Do you want to show all elements, but highlight only those, which two arrays contains? 
If so, you should:

1. `getItemCount()` method should return the size of the array, elements of which you want to show.
2. Lets say, you are showing items from the array called "mArrayListElements".
   Try this code:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(TagsViewHolder holder, int position) {
     if(mArrayListSelectedTags.contains(mArrayListElements(position))){
       View v = holder.itemView.findViewById(YOUR_VIEW_ID);
       v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVincular));
     }
   }
   ```
3. You have problems with your id in this line of code:

   ```
    holder.itemView.findViewById(mArrayListElementos.indexOf(mArrayListSelectedTags.get(i)));
   ```

You have two ways to resolve it.

First.
 If you need to change color of the background of the whole view, you can just use:

```
holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVincular));
```

Second.
If you need to change color of some part of your view, you need to set id to the view (that you want to change) in the xml file and then use that id in the method `findViewById(R.id.YOUR_ID)`.

For example:
In xml

```
<View
android:id="@+id/my_view"
...
/>
```

In code

```
holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
```

P.S. By the way, you should keep in mind, that RecyclerView reuses ViewHolders so you need to handle both cases, when you need to change color for your view when both arrays contains your item, and set default color back, when only main array contains item. Otherwise you will have some view`s backgrounds colored in the wrong color, while scrolling.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, its throwing now that View v is null

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: @Todd what is the id of your view in the xml file?
Your code:
holder.itemView.findViewById(mArrayListElements.indexOf(mArrayListSelectedTags.get(position)));

is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by doing

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mArrayListSelectedTags.size(); i++) {
           View v = holder.itemView;
           v.findViewById(mArrayListElementos.indexOf(mArrayListSelectedTags.get(i)));
           v.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorVincular));

        }
```

Thanks all for the help !